# Why is password emphasized in Postgresql pgadmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I know that PostgreSQL does not list password as a reserved key word in [its documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

However when I write it in pgadmin, it is emboldened and color emphasized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually PGADMIN change the color and style of all keywords(Reserved or Non-Reserved). As per documentation

> According to the standard, reserved key words are the only real key words; they are never allowed as identifiers. Non-reserved key words only have a special meaning in particular contexts and can be used as identifiers in other contexts.

So `PASSWORD` is a non reserved keyword. Due to that PGADMIN is highlighting it but still you can use it as an identifier.